# Can I create a custom function in Excel that returns the value of a specific range of cells with a worksheet name as the input?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I am fairly new to VBA coding. What I am hoping to produce is a simple function I can use in any sheet of the workbook as I would a predefined function (like SUM, COUNT, etc), with the purpose being to return the sum of a range of cells in a specified worksheet.

What I have tried is:

```vba
Function fn_LastRow(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)
    Dim Sum1 As Long
    Sum1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sht.Range("B1:B10"))
    GetNumeric = Sum1
    
End Function
```

My first issue is understanding how to be able to input a worksheet name, like "January 2022" as the input of my user defined function. Any tips?

-------- FOLLOW UP TO ORIGINAL --------

As a follow-up, I am now trying to create function that tells me the last row with the sheet name input. Based on google results I know finding last row/column is fairly basic, and there many ways to do it (and lots of do's and don'ts). That said, I am curious at my results and have been unable to find clarity in existing results.

What I now have is:

```vba
Function jm_cellvalue(ByVal Sht_name As String)

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell_value As Long
    Dim Adr As String
    Set Sht = Worksheets(Sht_name)
    cell_value = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Adr = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address
    
    jm_cellvalue = cell_value
    MsgBox Adr

End Function
```

The result I get for the variables is:
cell_value = 1
Adr = $1:$1048576

The particular last cell doesn't bother me at the moment, but I can't understand why the cell_value = ...xlLastCell).Row would return a 1 with that address?

----- FURTHER UPDATE -------

Running the same logic as a sub produces the correct result, it's only when run as a function the resulting "last cell" is incorrect, as well as the row incorrectly =1 as well.

Comment: Your input is a `String`, not a `Worksheet`, and you need to then create a worksheet reference from that string.

Comment: You will also want to make it volatile.  By not including the range in the conditions it will not recalc automatically on changes to those ranges.

Comment: To be clear, you're not trying to pull from closed workbooks, Right?

Comment: *`GetNumeric = Sum1`* ?? - if this should be the function result you try to return, you'd have to assign `Sum1` via `fn_LastRow = Sum1`; if the function name itself is a typo, then *edit* your post and correct the function name to `GetNumeric` (btw sounding more comprehensive for a sum than `fn_LastRow`).

Comment: Correct, not tying to pull from closed workbooks. Thank you for the help, these comments answer my question.
@T.M - Thank you for picking up on this, I realized it later and forgot to update the original question